# Formatting a MYSQL Database to precede with a single leading zero only

Tags: mysql, database, zerofill

So I have tried to use unsigned zero fill for this problem but this keeps happening to fill the field out to the length of 7:

[MYSQL Database zerofill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYtvI.png)

I want it to just precede with a single 0 before the area code.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. I simply set up the MYSQL data types to VARCHAR before importing the .csv data file so it would keep the leading 0 of the area codes.